# How to recognize file in directory

Tags: python

I am having a problem finding my file in my directory within Jupyter Notebook. Its puzzling because it recognizes the file path but not the file. Any suggestions?

Ive tried changing the double backslashes with single forward slashes and including .csv at the end but still end up with the same results.

```
os.path.isdir("C:\\Users\\ABakk1\\PyCharmProjects\\data\\control_access")
True

os.path.isfile("C:\\Users\\ABakk1\\PyCharmProjects\\data\\control_access\\test")
False
```

Comment: `os.path.isfile("C:\\Users\\ABakk1\\PyCharmProjects\\data\\control_access\\test")` doesn't contain the file extension so it's really not possible know know how that failed (though you say it does)

Comment: @roganjosh that worked this time... this is strange